# URDF Joint Mimic Tag Not Functioning

Tags: ros, joint, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the new mimic tag that is included in the [urdf/XML/joint element](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/joint), like so (this is xacro):

```
  <joint name="gripper_finger_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="gripper_roll_link"/>
    <child link="gripper_finger_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.026 .017 0" rpy="${1.04*M_PI} ${M_PI/2} ${34.58*M_PI/180}" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="300" velocity="1" lower="${-53*M_PI/180}" upper="${0*M_PI/180}"/>
    <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
  </joint>

  ...

  <joint name="r_gripper_aft_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="gripper_roll_link"/>
    <child link="r_gripper_aft_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.026 -0.011  0" rpy="${1.345*M_PI} ${M_PI/2} ${34.58*M_PI/180}" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="300" velocity="1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" />
    <mimic joint="gripper_finger_joint" multiplier="-1.0" offset="0.0" />
    <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
  </joint>
```

However, in Rviz the mimic joints are not working with the Rviz **RobotModel** plugin. What could I be missing?

The entire urdf is available [here](https://github.com/davetcoleman/clam/blob/454c535134ab0377b193a33d1b5c38db914d39dc/clam_description/urdf/clam.urdf).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60846/urdf-joint-mimic-tag-not-functioning/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are you using to visualize the robot? Can you try the RobotModel as well as the MoveIt! MotionPlanningDisplay ?  Is there a difference?

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-04-18**:
Ah, yes, mimic joint does work in the MoveIt! MotionPlanningDisplay. However, it does not work using the RobotModel plugin, which seems like an issue since the mimic joint is part of URDF, a non-MoveIt specific component.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-04-18**:
Additionally, it seems like the RobotState MoveIt plugin works too, but I don't know what to put in the "Robot State Topic" to make it reflect the current published TFs from the controllers.

**Comment by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) on 2013-04-18**:
Alright. Does your system publish the value of the mimic joints on /joint_states ? I expect not. This is redundant information, but I believe it is what the robot_state_publisher uses. I guess the robot_state_publisher needs to be updated to 'fill in the blanks', where the blanks are mimic joints.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-04-18**:
Currently David Lu!!!'s joint state publisher does that, but I was assuming it had already been integrated into robot_state_publisher when I heard that mimic tags were officially supported.

**Comment by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) on 2013-04-18**:
Please assign a ticket to robot_state_publisher and we'll continue the discussion there.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-04-18**:
Ticket posted: https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/issues/1